# How to associate a color with each cluster of points?

Tags: matlab, octave

I am given some `points` and some `centroids` representing the centers of some clusters of points. I am asked to determine what cluster each point belongs to and then plot it (using `scatter3`), and each cluster of points should be colored differently.

How can I generate an initial `cluster_colors` matrix of size `Cx3`, where `C` is the number of clusters/ centroids? It doesn't really matter what the colors are, but they should be easily distinguishable. Also, I don't know the number of clusters beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To color the points with [SCATTER3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/scatter3.html) you actually need Nx1 matrix (`CLR` in the example below), there N is the number of points. This matrix can contain the cluster number, for example.

```
scatter3(X,Y,Z,[],CLR)
```

The colors will be used from the current colormap. To set the colormap you do need a Cx3 matrix. You can get it from any existing colormap. See [COLORMAP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colormap.html) for more details.

For example,

```
colormap(jet(C))
```

Actually the number of colors in the colormap don't have to be equal to the number of clusters.

You can also create your own colormap using [MATLAB colormap editor](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colormapeditor.html). Or find many nice colormaps on the FileExchange, like [this one](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29702-generate-maximally-perceptually-distinct-colors).